# Decrypt AES data on android that comes from a C# MVC4 server

Tags: c#, java, android, asp.net-mvc-4, cryptography

i know there are many similar topics here on SO, but unfortunately none of them could solve my issue.

What i want to do:
Encrypt a string on the server Side with AES, send it to my android client in the form on a byte[] and then decrypt it to the original string. - kind of what an encryption is used for

**UPDATE-Begin:**
As Mikkel K. suggested there was a problem with my conversion, but i fixed that now.

My new problem is, that the message gets not decrypted correctly.
I changed my debug output to bit representation now.

**Example**

So, what i send from **servside** is:

Unencrypted Message: This test will show whether it works or not!!!

Unencrypted MessageBytes: 1010100 | 1101000 | 1101001 | 1110011 | 100000 | 1110100 | 1100101 | 1110011 | 1110100 | 100000 | 1110111 | 1101001 | 1101100 | 1101100 | 100000 | 1110011 | 1101000 | 1101111 | 1110111 | 100000 | 1110111 | 1101000 | 1100101 | 1110100 | 1101000 | 1100101 | 1110010 | 100000 | 1101001 | 1110100 | 100000 | 1110111 | 1101111 | 1110010 | 1101011 | 1110011 | 100000 | 1101111 | 1110010 | 100000 | 1101110 | 1101111 | 1110100 | 100001 | 100001 | 100001 |

Encrypted MessageBytes: 11010101 | 100 | 10000011 | 100101 | 11011111 | 11101001 | 11000010 | 10101011 | 1001 | 1101001 | 101100 | 11010000 | 10001001 | 11010010 | 11110110 | 101011 | 0 | 10 | 10110 | 1101100 | 111100 | 10101001 | 1110 | 11101000 | 11100111 | 1110110 | 10000101 | 1101000 | 1111111 | 111111 | 11111100 | 11100100 | 11000010 | 10111101 | 10101110 | 11001111 | 1100101 | 11100010 | 11100101 | 10001001 | 10000110 | 10111010 | 1101110 | 100100 | 1001110 | 11111111 | 10100001 | 11110010 |

what i get on **android(client side)**:

Encrypted MessageBytes: 11010101 | 100 | 10000011 | 100101 | 11011111 | 11101001 | 11000010 | 10101011 | 1001 | 1101001 | 101100 | 11010000 | 10001001 | 11010010 | 11110110 | 101011 | 0 | 10 | 10110 | 1101100 | 111100 | 10101001 | 1110 | 11101000 | 11100111 | 1110110 | 10000101 | 1101000 | 1111111 | 111111 | 11111100 | 11100100 | 11000010 | 10111101 | 10101110 | 11001111 | 1100101 | 11100010 | 11100101 | 10001001 | 10000110 | 10111010 | 1101110 | 100100 | 1001110 | 11111111 | 10100001 | 11110010 |

Unencrypted MessageBytes: 1101111 | 1110010 | 1101011 | 1110011 | 100000 | 1101111 | 1110010 | 100000 | 1101110 | 1101111 | 1110100 | 100001 | 100001 | 100001 | 100000 | 1110011 | 1101000 | 1101111 | 1110111 | 100000 | 1110111 | 1101000 | 1100101 | 1110100 | 1101000 | 1100101 | 1110010 | 100000 | 1101001 | 1110100 | 100000 | 1110111 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

Message: orks or not!!! show whether it w

As you can see the Encrypted bytes do match, whereas there are some problems with the unencrypted bytes:

it seems like the characters "This test will" are overriden with the characters "orks or not!!!" as the count of the characters match

**Note1:** the count of the characters that are overriden differs with different messages.

**Note2:** as you can see from my code piece below, i cut off the "0" at the end, thats why there are no "garbage-characters" at the end.

Here is my decryption algorithm:

```
private String AESDecrypt(byte[] keyBytes, byte[] IVBytes, byte[] input)
            throws Exception {
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS7Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "AES"),
                new IvParameterSpec(IVBytes));

        // decrypt
        byte[] decrptedBytes = new byte[input.length];
        cipher.update(input, 0, input.length, decrptedBytes, 0);
        cipher.doFinal(decrptedBytes, 0);


        Log.i("demo", "Unencrypted MessageBytes: " + showByteArray(decrptedBytes));

        // find length of value
        int end = decrptedBytes.length;
        for (int i = 0; i < decrptedBytes.length; i++) {
            // Log.i("demo", "value: " + decrptedBytes[i]);
            if (decrptedBytes[i] == 0) {
                end = i;
                break;
            }
        }
        // Log.i("demo", "length: " + end);

        // make string in ascii
        byte[] value = Arrays.copyOf(decrptedBytes, end);
        String message = new String(value, "US-ASCII");

        return message;
    }
```

So, my new question is why the decryption fails?

**UPDATE-End**

What my problem is:
i already tried to fix my app for various hours, so i think i narrowed the problem down.

i think my transition works, because i checked the byte array of my key, IV-Parameter and the encrypted message.
In other words, i should have the key, the Inizalisation vector and the encrypted message on android. (But there is one thing that i am wondering about - more on this point later.)
The next step is to try to decrypt it to the unencrypted byte array - and here is the bug - the unencrypted byte array does not match the unencrypted byte array on the server - so the decryption didn´t work.

Note: 
On the server side i use CBC CipherMode and PKCS7 PaddingMode.
When i choose the same CipherMode and PaddingMode on Android, however i get a "Bad Block Padding"-Exception.
So for debugging purposes i uses NoPadding, which just should add some garbage at the end of my string i thought, but as my whole string seems to be garbage, the problem must be deeper in my code.

Here is the Code exammple now

**C# - Serverside**

```
 public ActionResult Sync(Int32 command, string data = "", string parameter = "")
        {
String message = "test";
Aes myAes = Aes.Create();
myAes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC; //should be default, but just set it
myAes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7; //should be default, but just set it

byte[] myKey = myAes.Key;
byte[] myIV = myAes.IV;
byte[] messageBytes = ByteConverter.GetBytes(message);
byte[] encryptedMessageBytes = AESEncrypt(messageBytes, myAes);


//some debugging output
Debug.WriteLine("KeyBytes: " + showByteArray(myKey));
Debug.WriteLine("IVBytes: " + showByteArray(myIV));
Debug.WriteLine("Unencrypted Message: " + message);
Debug.WriteLine("Unencrypted MessageBytes: " + showByteArray(messageBytes));
Debug.WriteLine("Encrypted MessageBytes: " + showByteArray(encryptedMessageBytes));
Debug.WriteLine("-----------------");

var PacketData = new { Key = myAes.Key, IV = myAes.IV, Message = encryptedMessageBytes};
return Json(PacketData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}

public String showByteArray(byte[] arr)
        {
            String s = "";
            foreach (byte b in arr)
            {
                s += b + "|";
            }
            return s;
        }



        static public byte[] AESEncrypt(byte[] DataToEncrypt, Aes aesAlg)
        {
            try
            {
                ICryptoTransform encryptor = aesAlg.CreateEncryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV);
                return encryptor.TransformFinalBlock(DataToEncrypt, 0, DataToEncrypt.Length);
            }
            catch (CryptographicException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                return null;
            }
        }
```

I hope i didn´t already fail at the encryption.

**Android - Code:**

```
public void getMessage(String serverResponse){
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(serverResponse);

JSONArray AesKeyArray = obj.getJSONArray("Key");
JSONArray IVArray = obj.getJSONArray("IV");
JSONArray MessageArray = obj.getJSONArray("Message");

// convert to java byteArrays
//**so here could be another part where i failed - as mentioned above**:
// c# byte goes from 0 to 255, whereas java byte goes from -128-127, so i just subtracted //128 from each c# byte, to get the java byte
//is this the correct conversation????

byte[] AesKeyBytes = JsonArrayToByteArray(AesKeyArray);
byte[] IVBytes = JsonArrayToByteArray(IVArray);
byte[] Messagebytes = JsonArrayToByteArray(MessageArray);

Log.i("demo", "log start");
Log.i("demo", "IVByte: " + showByteArray(IVBytes));
Log.i("demo", "KeyByte: " + showByteArray(AesKeyBytes));
Log.i("demo", "Encrypted MessageBytes: " + showByteArray(Messagebytes));

byte[] unencryptedMessageBytes = AESDecrypt(AesKeyBytes, IVBytes,Messagebytes);

Log.i("demo", "Unencrypted Messagebytes: " + showByteArray(unencryptedMessageBytes));

}

private byte[] JsonArrayToByteArray(JSONArray arr) throws Exception {
        byte[] result = new byte[arr.length()];
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++) {
    int byteAsIntCSharp = (Integer) arr.get(i); // have as integer 0-255(c# style)
        int byteAsIntJava = byteAsIntCSharp - 128;// make it javastyle(-128 to 127
            byte byteJava = (byte) byteAsIntJava;

            result[i] = byteJava;

        }

        return result;
    }

private String showByteArray(byte[] arr) {
        String s = "";
        for (byte b : arr) {
            s += String.valueOf(b) + "|";
        }
        return s;
}

private byte[] AESDecrypt(byte[] keyBytes, byte[] IVBytes, byte[] input)
            throws Exception {
        // Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS7Padding");
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/NoPadding");

        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "AES"),
                new IvParameterSpec(IVBytes));
        byte[] decrptedBytes = new byte[input.length];
        cipher.update(input, 0, input.length, decrptedBytes, 0);
        int radomPT = cipher.doFinal(decrptedBytes, 0);
        return decrptedBytes;
    }
```

The output of the above is:

**C# - Side:**

KeyBytes: 51|188|150|140|49|73|67|32|32|161|178|15|206|246|76|191|253|40|178|93|245|251|164|161|253|6|6|37|151|31|206|74|

IVBytes: 127|51|13|45|71|216|102|225|47|186|105|85|114|8|246|28|

Unencrypted Message: test

Unencrypted MessageBytes: 116|0|101|0|115|0|116|0|

Encrypted MessageBytes: 42|159|126|29|7|157|63|150|100|124|224|230|167|59|188|185|

**Android output:**

IVByte: -1|-77|-115|-83|-57|88|-26|97|-81|58|-23|-43|-14|-120|118|-100|

KeyByte: -77|60|22|12|-79|-55|-61|-96|-96|33|50|-113|78|118|-52|63|125|-88|50|-35|117|123|36|33|125|-122|-122|-91|23|-97|78|-54|

Encrypted MessageBytes: -86|31|-2|-99|-121|29|-65|22|-28|-4|96|102|39|-69|60|57|

Unencrypted Messagebytes: -122|-126|107|24|109|-88|-75|39|39|16|8|89|-70|-15|-114|85|

As you can see IVByte, KeyByte and Encrypted-bytes seem to match(except for the java - c# differnces), but the unencrypted Bytes do not.

So i am wondering whether these encryption/decryption methods are just not compatible or i failed in my code.

I really hope anybody around here can help me. :)

sincerly, Lukas

Comment: FYI, Java calls PKCS #7 padding "PKCS5Padding".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you encrypt with PKCS#7 padding and then decrypt with no padding, it should work just fine, except that you get padding at the end. The padding is just x bytes containing the number x.

I stumbled upon the comment "c# byte goes from 0 to 255, whereas java byte goes from -128-127, so i just subtracted //128 from each c# byte, to get the java byte" and I think that might be your problem (or one problem anyway).

This isn't how [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) works. Try to fix that first and see if it works.

Comment: so, i read up a little on bit and bytes and as you suggested my conversion failed, because i just thought about the displayed value, and not about the bits - that really are important.
after investing some time into a new conversion and i got it working.

there is still a problem, so i updated my question, maybe you know something about that too?

thanks, sir

Comment: i invested more time into this and learned that i had some issues that made my process fail.
i accepted your answer as the most critic issue at that time was the way i treated my bytes - as you mentioned that this could be a problem.